# Postie only sends first word of message

Tags: powershell

I'm converting my batch scripts to PowerShell and I have it all done except the last line which sends a confirmation email via `Postie.exe`.

```
$subject = "Kiva Extract"
$msg = "Kiva_Extract has been completed for July."

& "C:\cmucwin\postie.exe" -host:myServer -from:$env:username@myDomain -to:me@myDomain -s:$subject -msg:$msg
```

This worked fine in CMD, of course with little modifications that I had to do to convert to PowerShell. Now it works but it is only sending the first word of the message and subject. The email I get has:

> Subject: Kiva
>   Message: Kiva_Extract

If I output the `$subject` and `$msg` variable they are correct. What I am doing wrong?

This is the line used in my Batch script

```
postie -host:myServer -from:%USERNAME%@myDomain -to:%dbaManager% -s:"Kiva Extract" -msg:"Kiva_Extract has been completed for %curmonth%."
```

This works fine. Here is the lines I am trying to get to work. I have tried it without variables and it still doesn't work. I think it either has to do with the 'space' character being treated like an EOF or 'carriage return' or how it parses and doesn't read the parenthesis right. I have used the ` to keep the quotes in the string and that doesn't help either.

```
$date = Get-Date -format Y
$subject = "Kiva Extract"
$msg = "Kiva_Extract has been completed for $date"

& "C:\cmucwin\postie.exe" -host:myServer -from:$env:username@myDomain -to:myEmail -s:$subject -msg:$msg
```

Here is what I have found to work

```
& C:\cmucwin\postie.exe -host:$hostServer -from:$from -to:$to --% -s:"Kiva Extract" -msg:"Kiva_Extract has been completed for the month"
```

I had to use the --% to stop parsing. Apparently PowerShell was doing something to the arguments. The only problem I have now is that I wanted to use a variable in the message but now I can't because it won't parse it. Does anyone know how I could get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use postie?

```
send-mailmessage -from "User01 <user01@example.com>" -to "User02 <user02@example.com>", "User03 <user03@example.com>" -subject "Sending the Attachment" -body "Forgot to send the attachment. Sending now." -Attachments "data.csv" -priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure -smtpServer smtp.fabrikam.com
```

I tested it with my own setup and it works :)

Comment: Postie was just what my legacy scripts were using. This worked perfectly. Thanks. I never thought to see if PowerShell had a mail function.

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* that you'd need to wrap the message in quotes.  Try this:

```
$subject = "Kiva Extract"
$msg = '"Kiva_Extract has been completed for July."'

& "C:\cmucwin\postie.exe" -host:myServer -from:$env:username@myDomain -to:me@myDomain -s:$subject -msg:$msg
```

Or this:

```
$serverhost = "-host:myServer"
$from = "-from:$env:username@myDomain"
$to = "-to:me@myDomain"
$subj = '"-s:Kiva Extract"'
$msg = '-msg:"Kiva_Extract has been completed for July."'

& "C:\cmucwin\postie.exe" $serverhost $from $to $subj $msg
```

Comment: I do not have a complete grasp of the quotes in PowerShell yet but this did not help. I have tried many different combinations of quotes to no avail. The string is stored fine, it just doesn't work right with Postie. I have even replaces the variables with the string and it still didn't work. `postie.exe ... -msg:"Test message content"` and that only puts "Test" in the message.

Comment: Hm.. can you post the the CMD version that does work?

Comment: I have added it to the original post. Thanks

Comment: This is strange.  I updated my answer, give that a try.

Comment: This is really bugging me. It still only sends the first word of the subject and message. One thing to note on your answer is that you cannot use `$host`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Invoke-Command and scriptblock?

This is something that I have used for installing Google Chrome.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock { & cmd /c "msiexec.exe /i c:\temp\chrome\Bradley\googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi" }
```

Comment: I did try this. It gives the same results. Only the first word of the string gets into the email.

Answer (score 0):

`echoargs` utility from [PSCX](https://pscx.codeplex.com/releases) comes handy in such situations.

If I run this:

```
$subject = "Kiva Extract"
$msg = "Kiva_Extract has been completed for July."
& ".\EchoArgs.exe" -host:myServer -from:$env:username@myDomain -to:me@myDomain -s:$subject -msg:$msg
```

I get:

```
Arg 0 is <-host:myServer>
Arg 1 is <-from:xxx@myDomain>
Arg 2 is <-to:me@myDomain>
Arg 3 is <-s:Kiva>
Arg 4 is <Extract>
Arg 5 is <-msg:Kiva_Extract>
Arg 6 is <has>
Arg 7 is <been>
Arg 8 is <completed>
Arg 9 is <for>
Arg 10 is <July.>
```

So, if I add some quotes to the arguments I get:

```
$subject = "Kiva Extract"
$msg = "Kiva_Extract has been completed for July."
& ".\EchoArgs.exe" "-host:myServer" "-from:$env:username@myDomain" "-to:me@myDomain" "-s:$subject" "-msg:$msg"
```

It starts to produce:

```
Arg 0 is <-host:myServer>
Arg 1 is <-from:xxx@myDomain>
Arg 2 is <-to:me@myDomain>
Arg 3 is <-s:Kiva Extract>
Arg 4 is <-msg:Kiva_Extract has been completed for July.>
```

which should work for you.

Alternatively, you can use array to pass arguments with spaces:

```
$a = @("-host:myServer", "-from:$env:username@myDomain", "-to:me@myDomain", "-s:Kiva Extract", "-msg:Kiva_Extract has been completed for July.");
& ".\EchoArgs.exe" $a
```

Produces pretty much the same result.

As for other suggestions, quoting strings does not really do much:

```
$subject = "Kiva Extract"                                                                           
$msg = '"Kiva_Extract has been completed for July."'                                                
& ".\EchoArgs.exe" -host:myServer -from:$env:username@myDomain -to:me@myDomain -s:$subject -msg:$msg
```

produces:

```
Arg 0 is <-host:myServer>         
Arg 1 is <-from:xxx@myDomain>
Arg 2 is <-to:me@myDomain>        
Arg 3 is <-s:Kiva>                
Arg 4 is <Extract>                
Arg 5 is <-msg:Kiva_Extract>      
Arg 6 is <has>                    
Arg 7 is <been>                   
Arg 8 is <completed>              
Arg 9 is <for>                    
Arg 10 is <July.>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be quite the answer you're looking for, but if you're already in the business of converting old batch files to PowerShell scripts, why not take advantage of the Send-MailMessage cmdlet instead?

```
$subject = "Kiva Extract"
$msg = "Kiva_Extract has been completed for July."

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "myServer" -From "$env:username@myDomain" -To "me@myDomain" -Subject $subject -Body $msg
```

Just my two cents.